# What is affected by ReferenceProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

In reference to these two questions *(see links below)* and the Google AppEngine doc, I got a little bit confused:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Story(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)

story = db.get(story_key)
author_name = story.author.name
```

*Source: Google*

The doc example indicates that the object which has the `ReferenceProperty` is the "owner" object, which (can have) has such an object as relational item.

The links below show it vice-versa:
The object which has the `ReferenceProperty` is the "owned" object.
Now my question is, what is right, or what aspect of the `ReferenceProperty` am I missing/misunderstanding?

- [GQL with two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002856/gql-with-two-tables/2003187#2003187)
- [Google app engine ReferenceProperty relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210321/google-app-engine-referenceproperty-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of ownership here is purely semantic, ReferenceProperty fields are only used for navigability.

Comment: So it just have to exist in one Model, and just represents a link, it is not important where it has to be plaeced?

Comment: absolutely! it all depends on how convenient it is for you.

Answer (score 1):

References imply only referentiality - a "has a" relationship, if you like - not ownership. In your example, a Story "has an" Author. Another way to think about it is in the same way you would use a variable to refer to an object in OO.